# How to execute SQL query?

Tags: 7, forms, database, search

I have a text in $text, I need to do

```
select 'nid' from 'node' where 'title'=$text
```

later I need to do this

```
select 'column_name' from 'table_name' where entity_id = nid
```

then I need to print the column name. can you tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Please use below working code

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->condition('n.title', $text, '=');
$nid = $query->execute()->fetchField();

//get column name from nid
$query = db_select('table_name', 't');
$query->fields('t', array('column_name'));
$query->condition('t.entity_id', $nid, '=');
$column_name = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE title = :text", array(
  ':text' => $text)
)->fetch(PDO:.FETCH_OBJ);

$result = db_query("SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE nid = :nid", array(
  ':nid' => $result[0]->nid)
)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

You could also use a dynamic select query like this:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.title', $text);
$query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$results = $query->execute();
// get the first nid from the resultset - I think this should work - not tested
$nid = $results->nid;

// select an entry based on the above nid
$query = db_select('table_name', 't');
$query->condition('t.entity_id', $nid);
$query->fields('t', array('column_name'));
$results = $query->execute();
```

A better approach might be to use one query if you only need the data from the second query:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.title', $title);
$query->join('table_name', 't');
$query->condition('t.entity_id', 'n.nid');
$query->fields('t', array('column_name'));
$results = $query->execute();
```

Then you could loop through the results like this:

```
foreach ($results as $result):
  print $result->column_name;
endforeach;
```

Comment: i need to select a column from another table where entity id= nid and print it.

Comment: @ana - Did the above work?

Comment: no it did not, there is only one element in result. why are you using array_shift?

Comment: @ana - I never tested the code, just wrote it as an example, I though it might return more then one result =) The last example should work and it should also be the best approach if you only want to use the `column_name`. Notice that I join the second table based on the nid in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

1. `db_query("select 'column_name' from 'table_name' where entity_id = :nid", array(:nid => $nid));`
2. for eg.

   `$result = db_select('node', 'n')
       ->fields('n')
       ->condition('nid', $node->nid,'=')
       ->condition('status', 0,'>')
       ->condition('uid', array(1,5,7),'IN')
       ->execute()
       ->fetchAssoc();`